# Sony Xperia XZ Premium goes out of silent mode when connecting to Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, sony-xperia, vibration, silent-mode, 9.0-pie

I have my phone set to silent (vibrate) mode and have noticed that when I connect to a bluetooth device, the phone 'exits' silent mode and the ringer volume is enabled again. This is especially annoying as I like to use a scheduled silence app and have to remember to manually enter silent mode again.

I believe this may have been caused by a recent update as my phone has regular updates and the issue has only started occurring recently.

The phone is a Sony Xperia XZ Premium running Android version 9, build number 47.2.A.2.33

Comment: Is the silent modeactive while connected to bluetooth?

Comment: @helper no, it exits silent mode upon connection to bluetooth